# Group stats problem

Tags: qgis

I've just installed group stats, but when I started working with it, the drag and drop does not work. I grab the items (attributes or functions) and they do not drop in their places.

Does anyone know what's my problem?

Comment: Which QGIS version and GroupStats plugin version are you using?

Comment: QGIS 2.18.5. But I just resoved the issue. I just reinstalled, than exited qgis. When I open it back it was alright